# How to install SSL for python 2.5 on Debian Linux?

Tags: python, ssl, installation

### Question

How do I install SSL for Python 2.5 on Debian?

I have tried:

```
sudo easy_install ssl
```

But getting:

```
$ python setup.py build
looking for /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h
looking for /usr/include/krb5.h
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'ssl._ssl2' extension
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.5
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.5/ssl
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I./ssl/2.5.1 -I/usr/include/python2.5 -c ssl/_ssl2.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.5/ssl/_ssl2.o
In file included from ssl/_ssl2.c:75:
./ssl/2.5.1/socketmodule.h:45:33: error: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: No such file or directory
./ssl/2.5.1/socketmodule.h:46:30: error: bluetooth/rfcomm.h: No such file or directory
./ssl/2.5.1/socketmodule.h:47:29: error: bluetooth/l2cap.h: No such file or directory
./ssl/2.5.1/socketmodule.h:48:27: error: bluetooth/sco.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ssl/_ssl2.c:75:
./ssl/2.5.1/socketmodule.h:98: error: field ‘bt_l2’ has incomplete type
./ssl/2.5.1/socketmodule.h:99: error: field ‘bt_rc’ has incomplete type
./ssl/2.5.1/socketmodule.h:100: error: field ‘bt_sco’ has incomplete type
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

### Solution

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
sudo rm /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/ssl/__init__.pyc
```

Comment: Do you have the python dev packages? Edit: you should post that as an answer, don't put it in your question.

Comment: I guess he have. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Is there a reason that an answer isn't selected?

Answer (score 8):

For reference, you must install `libbluetooth-dev`.

Comment: +1 I had the same problem as the OP, this fixed it.  He needs to accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you shouldn't compile your own version of python ssl module for several reasons:

- you won't get automatic security updates of your python ssl module;
- you won't get smooth upgrade path if you decide to upgrade Debian system on your server.

The best way to obtain python ssl module is to install it from official Debian repositories using apt-get:

```
apt-get install python-openssl
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: System can't find ssl lib in this way for me. (i can't `>>> import ssl` is it simmilar or different problem?

Comment: This is not helpful if most of your installations will be virtualenv.

Comment: @JackLeo `>>> import OpenSSL`

Comment: This does not help if your goal is to use the backported Python "ssl" module: python-openssl is not the same thing.